# How to create a formula with variables and string on excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I want this line:

```
./command.sh -id IDVAL -amount MONEY -assignment SIGNVAL -reason "goodjob"
```

as a formula in excel. `IDVAL` is in cell `A2`, `MONEY` is in `B2`, `SIGNVAL` is in `C2` (for the first line.. for the second line, `IDVAL` is in `A3`, `MONEY` in `B3` etc.).

To make this a formula, what I tried was

```
./command.sh -id =A2 -amount =B2 -assignment =C2 -reason "goodjob"
```

but it recognizes `=A2` as a string (doesn't read what is in `A2`). How would I get it to read what is in the `A2` cell rather than having it as a string?

Edit: I copy pasted this into the cell / "fx" bar near the top of excel. I also tried

```
./command.sh -id =evaluate(=A2)
```

but that doesn't work either.

Comment: are you trying to launch a shell command from a VBA macro?

Comment: @A.S.H, I suspect he's trying to run a single command many times with different parameters that are listed in Excel, so he's just trying to generate those commands which he'll then copy/paste into a command window to bulk run them.

Comment: @Marc, yeah, it looks like preparing a batch for Unix.

Comment: @A.S.H not OP but what she was trying to do was create a list of commands based on variables which were in an excel file. These commands were then all copy pasted together into the terminal (has to do with AWS Mechanical Turk). Marc was correct.

Comment: @user2719875 Thanks, I agreed with Marc's answer as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate strings using ampersand `&`:

```
="./command.sh -id "&A2&" -amount "&B2&" -assignment "&C2&" -reason "&CHAR(34)&"goodjob"&CHAR(34)
```

I often use `CHAR(34)` as the double-quote character.

But you can also escape the double quotes around "goodjob" by doubling them like this:

```
="./command.sh -id "&A2&" -amount "&B2&" -assignment "&C2&" -reason ""goodjob"""
```